# Error on FTP file import - Warning: ftp_get(): php_connect_nonb() failed:

Tags: product-import, ftp

I use a third-party extension to deal with product imports - Firebear's Improved Import/Export (Magento 2). It works fine when I upload a file locally but when I try to import a file via FTP from the client's machine I get the following error:

Warning: ftp_get(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Io/Ftp.php on line 214

I have sent a ticket to the extension owners but think it might be more to do with the settings on one of the servers, rather than the extension itself. Has anyone come across this before? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766158/php-connect-nonb-failed-operation-now-in-progress-115-with-tls-ssl-encryp

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Magento server's firewall was blocking some ports which were needed.